# Tool to intercept RESTful webservices

Tags: web-services, rest, restful-url

May be this has been asked before but i coud'nt find a proper tool to do this.
What is the best tool to place in the middle of a RESTful webservice and monitor it without port redirection.

Something like TCPMON which will show the full request from the client and the response from the server. For example if the response contain a JSON i should be able to view that??

Comment: Please be more specific, as there are a boatload of tools for this. Are you looking for an automated logging type tool, or something for debugging? Client side or server side?

Answer (score 2):

[Charles Proxy](http://www.charlesproxy.com/) is great for logging the full request/response for HTTP connections.